# Checking for Item in std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> Using std::find

Tags: c++

I have the following object

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vectorList;
```

Then I add to this using

```
std::vector<std::string> vec_tmp;
vec_tmp.push_back(strDRG);
vec_tmp.push_back(strLab);
if (std::find(vectorList.begin(), vectorList.end(), vec_tmp) == vectorList.end())
    vectorList.push_back(vec_tmp);
```

The `std::vector<std::string>`s contained `vectorList` are only ever 2-dimensional and there are no duplicates. This works great, but I now only want to check if `vectorList` contains an item that index zero equal to the current `strDrg`. In C# I would not even be thinking about this, but this does not seem straight forward using C++. How can I find if a vector exists in `vectorList` where `strDrg` already exists in `vectorList.at(i)[0]`?

*Note: I can use boost.*

Comment: Are you sure a `std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::string>>` would not be more appropriate if those sub-vectors always have exactly two elements? Also look into `std::map` and `std::set` as well as their unordered counterparts...

Comment: Yes, thanks very much. I an new to C++, I will swap this for a `tuple`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find_if` with a lambda:

```
std::find_if(vectorList.begin(), vectorList.end(), 
  [&strDrg](const std::vector<std::string>& v) { return v[0] == strDrg; });
```

It seems you don't need the full power of `vector` for you inner elements. Consider using:

```
std::vector<std::array<std::string, 2>>
```

instead.

Comment: Ah, great. I had no idea about `std::array`. Is the example above working with `std::vector<std::array<std::string, 2>>`?

Comment: @Killercam You will need to change the type the lambda accepts as a parameter to `const std::array<std::string, 2>&`. Otherwise it is the same. Or you could use `auto` as the argument if your compiler supports C++14.

Answer (score 1):

For doing exactly what you asked, `std::find_if` with a lambda as [@chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891666/checking-for-item-in-stdvectorstdvectorstdstring-using-stdfind#comment38666376_24891666) proposed in comments is the best:

```
std::find_if(ob.begin(), ob.end(),
    [&](const auto x){return x[0] == strDRG;});
// Replace auto with "decltype(ob[0])&" until
//you have a C++1y compiler. Might need some years.
```

But if you only ever have exactly two elements, consider using a `std::array<...>`, a `std::pair<...>` or a `std::tuple<...>` instead of the inner vector.

For tuple and pair, you need to access the first element differently:

pair : member `first`
tuple: use `get<0>(x);`

Comment: Thank you. These are data types I am not familiar with. It is appreciated. Will the above `find_if` work with `tuple` or `pair`?

Comment: Ah, I think that's c++1y. Seems your compiler is not there yet.

Comment: That's because it was an oversight by the C++ committee, rectified in C++14 I believe. Replace the auto with std::string.

Comment: Seems you need to explicitly give the argument type of the lambda, like pmr shows. Will be better when C++1y is deployed. (VS2013 still has some interesting non-conformancies to C++11).